# "Procedure or function expects parameter , which was not supplied."

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an error and it's:

"Procedure or function 'Consulta_RFC_Empresa' expects parameter '@RFC', which was not supplied."

This is the code i'm using on C#:

```
    public static Proveedor getDatosEmpresa(string erfc)
    {

        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        Proveedor empr = new Proveedor();
        try
        {

            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Consulta_RFC_Empresa", conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFC", @erfc);

            rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    empr.seteID("" + rdr["ID"]);
                    empr.seteRfc("" + rdr["RFC"]);
                    empr.seteTipo("" + rdr["Tipo"]);
                    empr.seteRazon("" + rdr["Razon_Social"]);
                }
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }

        return empr;
    }
```

and the Stored Procedure code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Consulta_RFC_Empresa]
(
    @RFC    VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT  TOP(1)
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ID))    AS  ID,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(RFC, ' ', '')))             AS  RFC,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(Tipo))              AS  Tipo,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(Razon_Social))  AS  Razon_Social
FROM    [Roga].[dbo].[RFC_Empresa_Buzon_Fiscal]
WHERE   RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(RFC, ' ', ''))) LIKE  @RFC
```

Can Some one help me??

Comment: If the error message tells you that a parameter is missing you might want to start by looking if you actually pass it. Basic debugging would have found this in about 5 seconds...

Comment: It's running with a Windows Service, and i have to run it like that to see the error on the event log... unable to debug from Visual Studio

Comment: (a) `erfc` could be `NULL` but in any case (b) shouldn't you be passing `erfc` not `@erfc`? What do you think C# thinks `@erfc` is? [Look closely](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VL8xQ.png).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you aren't adding the parameter it's expecting (you have an extra 'e' in `@eRFC`.

You have:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eRFC", erfc);
```

Try changing it to:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFC", erfc);
```

Comment: Still having the same error, but now the variable is @RFC

Answer (score 0):

Change your code
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFC", @erfc);

TO
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFC", erfc);

As "erfc" is the value you are passing to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Consulta_RFC_Empresa @RFC", conn);
```